# Убрать лишний уровень в много-уровневых (multi-level column names) столбцах в Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Добрый день, подскажите, как удалить строку из шапки таблицы этого фрейма,, которая содержит NaN?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пришел к этому таким кодом:

```
data = df.groupby(['Тип газопровода', 'Диаметр'])['Протяженность']
data = data.agg([{'Средняя протяженность':'mean', 
           'Кол-во объектов':'count', 
           'Общая протяженность':'sum'}])
data = data.reset_index(col_level=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените:

```
[{'Средняя протяженность':'mean', 
  'Кол-во объектов':'count', 
  'Общая протяженность':'sum'}]
```

на

```
{'Средняя протяженность':'mean', 
 'Кол-во объектов':'count', 
 'Общая протяженность':'sum'}
```

**Пример:**

исходный DataFrame:

```
In [94]: df
Out[94]:
   type  dm  length
0     1  50     110
1     1  50     111
2     1  63     112
3     2  32     113
4     2  32     114
5     2  32     115
6     3  50     116
7     3  50     117
8     3  50     118
9     3  80     119
```

Решение:

```
In [95]: funcs = {
    ...:     'count':        'count',
    ...:     'total length': 'sum',
    ...:     'avg. length':  'mean'
    ...: }
    ...:

In [96]: df.groupby(['type','dm'])['length'].agg(funcs).reset_index()
Out[96]:
   type  dm  count  total length  avg. length
0     1  50      2           221        110.5
1     1  63      1           112        112.0
2     2  32      3           342        114.0
3     3  50      3           351        117.0
4     3  80      1           119        119.0
```

для сравнения ваш вариант:

```
In [97]: df.groupby(['type','dm'])['length'].agg([funcs]).reset_index()
Out[97]:
  type  dm   NaN
           count total length avg. length
0    1  50     2          221       110.5
1    1  63     1          112       112.0
2    2  32     3          342       114.0
3    3  50     3          351       117.0
4    3  80     1          119       119.0
```

---

**универсальный вариант превращения многоуровневых столбцов в обычные:**

```
In [98]: rslt = df.groupby(['type','dm'])['length'].agg([funcs]).reset_index()

In [99]: rslt
Out[99]:
  type  dm   NaN
           count total length avg. length
0    1  50     2          221       110.5
1    1  63     1          112       112.0
2    2  32     3          342       114.0
3    3  50     3          351       117.0
4    3  80     1          119       119.0

In [100]: rslt.columns = [tup[1] if tup[1] else tup[0] for tup in rslt.columns]

In [101]: rslt
Out[101]:
   type  dm  count  total length  avg. length
0     1  50      2           221        110.5
1     1  63      1           112        112.0
2     2  32      3           342        114.0
3     3  50      3           351        117.0
4     3  80      1           119        119.0
```

Comment: добрый день! Спасибо за помощь, но на моих данных не проходит это решение. Все равно остается NaN и лишний level. А чем мое решение от вашего отличается? Те же методы, тот же порядок использования, у меня только строчек и переменных на одну больше.

Comment: @DenisNovik, разница в том, что вы используете конструкцию `[{...}]`, а я - `{...}`

Comment: увидел! Большое спасибо, теперь все как надо получилось. Вы на ветке pandas главный гуру!

Comment: @DenisNovik, всегда рад помочь :-)